# Intel network adaptor E810 -- driver loading issue "Direct firmware load for * failed with error -2"

Tags: drivers, network-interface, ethernet, intel

The Intel Network Adaptor E810-CQDA1 was not able to load `ice.pkg`. At first I suspected the path for `ice.pkg` was not correct and that I placed it along side the `ice.ko`, but that did not seem to help. I keep getting the following error: `Direct firmware load for intel/ice/ddp/ice.pkg failed with error -2`.

I'm running out of ideas to try. Any suggestions on how to debug driver loading issue? Many thanks.

System information and connectivity:

```
> uname -r
5.4.0-90-generic


> ethtool -i p1p1
driver: ice
version: 0.8.1-k
firmware-version: 2.30 0x80005d1e 0.0.0
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:10:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes

> lspci -vvv -s 0000:10:00.0
10:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 1592 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0001
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 68
    Region 0: Memory at e2000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 3: Memory at e1000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at fcf00000 [disabled] [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ice
    Kernel modules: ice
```

Kernel error logs:

```
> dmesg | grep "\<ice\>"
[    1.202918] ice: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection E800 Series Linux Driver - version 0.8.1-k
[    1.202919] ice: Copyright (c) 2018, Intel Corporation.
[    1.215600] ice 0000:10:00.0: The driver for the device detected a newer version of the NVM image than expected. Please install the most recent version of the network driver.
[    1.225732] ice 0000:10:00.0: firmware 5.3.7 api 1.7.4 nvm 2.30 0x80005d1e 0.0.0 build 0xa54f09ca
[    1.225770] ice 0000:10:00.0: Direct firmware load for intel/ice/ddp/ice.pkg failed with error -2
[    1.225771] ice 0000:10:00.0: The DDP package file was not found or could not be read. Entering Safe Mode
[    1.225773] ice 0000:10:00.0: Package download failed. Advanced features disabled - Device now in Safe Mode
[    1.252931] ice 0000:10:00.0 p1p1: renamed from eth0
```

Driver path:

```
tree /lib/modules/5.4.0-90-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/
/lib/modules/5.4.0-90-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/
├── ddp
│   ├── ice_comms-1.3.30.0.pkg
│   ├── ice_comms-1.3.30.0.zip
│   ├── ice.pkg -> ice_comms-1.3.30.0.pkg
│   ├── Intel_800_series_market_segment_DDP_license.txt
│   └── readme.txt
└── ice.ko
```

As for why I think this is an issue, I do not see packets in/out of this interface, and `ethtool p1p1` says:

```
......
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
......
```

Comparing this to another working instance, Speed and Duplex look wrong which makes me think the driver is not behaving right in the first place. The other reason, of course, is the `dmesg` error seen in the kernel error logs above.

References:

[1](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19660/intel-ethernet-800-series-telecommunication-comms-dynamic-device-personalization-ddp-package.html) I got DDP (`ice.pkg`) [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19660/intel-ethernet-800-series-telecommunication-comms-dynamic-device-personalization-ddp-package.html), version is 1.3.30.

[2](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19630/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-e810-series-devices-under-linux.html) I got the driver (`ice.ko`) [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19630/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-e810-series-devices-under-linux.html), built and loaded the module.  `modinfo ice` shows path and version.

[3](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ded746bfc94398d2ee9de315a187677b207b2004/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/ice_main.c#L4361) I was able to trace `dmesg` and saw that it prints [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ded746bfc94398d2ee9de315a187677b207b2004/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/ice_main.c#L4361) line. I don't have much of a clue as to what happens after.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to try, according to the READMEs is try to have a symbolic link of the DDP in the /lib/firmware and/or /lib/firmware/updates directory

```
ln -s /lib/modules/5.4.0-90-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ice/ice_comms-1.3.30.0.pkg /lib/firmware/ice.pkg
```

I went through the README documents of both the DDP and the driver itself. Seems like you are missing a step, which is **not considered mandatory in one of the documentations**, and in the other one it's not clear. It's like a basic step.

> Rename the ice_comms-x.x.x.x.pkg file as ice-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pkg,
> where 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is the unique 64-bit PCI Express device
> serial number (in hex) of the device you want the package downloaded
> on. The filename must include the complete serial number (including
> leading zeros) and be all lowercase. For example, if the 64-bit serial
> number is b887a3ffffca0568, then the file name would be
> ice-b887a3ffffca0568.pkg.
>
> To find the serial number from the PCI bus address, you can use the
> following command:

`# lspci -vv -s af:00.0 | grep -i Serial Capabilities: [150 v1] Device Serial Number b8-87-a3-ff-ff-ca-05-68`

You can use the following command to format the serial number without the
dashes:

`lspci -vv -s af:00.0 | grep -i Serial | awk '{print $7}' | sed s/-//g b887a3ffffca0568`

> 3. Copy the renamed DDP package file to /lib/firmware/updates/intel/ice/ddp/. If the directory does not yet
>    exist, create it before copying the file.
> 4. Unload all of the PFs on the device.
> 5. Reload the driver with the new package.

And in the main driver's README, they state the already obvious

> If the driver is unable to load the DDP package, the device will enter
> Safe Mode. Safe Mode disables advanced and performance features and
> supports only basic traffic and minimal functionality, such as
> updating the NVM or downloading a new driver or DDP package.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, it looks like the driver cannot find the Comms DDP Package that you have loaded (This generally due to bad file format on the ice.pkg). Alex's solution however is only if you want to load the DDP package on one unique NIC (based on its serial number), the following example shows how to do a basic install for all NICs on your host without the need to get serial numbers etc.

Using the latest Comms DDP package (1.3.37.0) as an example:

1. Download the Comms DDP Package from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19660/intel-ethernet-800-series-telecommunication-comms-dynamic-device-personalization-ddp-package.html) to your Linux host
2. On your Linux host, unzip the package:

   ```bash
   $ unzip 800\ Series\ DDP\ Comms\ Package\ 1.3.37.0.zip
   ```
3. Further unzip the nested package file into the `ice_comms` directory:

   ```bash
   $ unzip ice_comms-1.3.37.0.zip -d ice-comms/
   ```
4. Copy all the unzipped contents to `/lib/firmware/updates/intel/ice/ddp/`:

   ```bash
   $ sudo cp ice-comms/* /lib/firmware/updates/intel/ice/ddp/
   ```
5. Reload the ice driver to take in the new package:

   ```bash
   $ sudo modprobe -r ice; sudo modprobe ice
   ```
6. Confirm using `dmesg` that the driver has inserted the new DDP package.